# import android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat FAILS: cannot resolve ERROR

Tags: android-support-library, android-camera2

Using Ubuntu OS, AndroidStudio 2.3.3 (API 27), and the latest Gradle, I am trying to implement the code for Github/googlesamples/android-camera2raw wherein import android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat FAILS, giving a "cannot resolve" error. I have added the requisite library via the project/app/dependencies. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
```

to the app's build.gradle file.

Also note that FragmentCompact is deprecated in API level 27.1.0-
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat